# Check if date exists MySQL

Tags: mysql, date, triggers

Im validating an csv file that is being imported to the database via `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE` and im using a `before insert trigger` to achieve that (it is a dirty table, so when this process finishes i bulk correct data to another table). The problem is that i have a DATE field (Y-m-d) and if the script reads a non-existent date (ex: 2023-09-31, 2023-02-30) it throws:

> Invalid datetime format: 1292 Truncated incorrect date value: '2023-09-31'.

I've trying to *catch *the error within my trigger but it is always showing the same error in my frontend.

heres part of my trigger.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER `dirty_si_base_AFTER_INSERT` AFTER INSERT ON `dirty_si_base_AFTER_INSERT` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN

[...]
DECLARE fecha_valida_notificacion BOOLEAN;



    [...]
    
     -- Verificamos si la fecha fallo es válida
     
   SET fecha_valida_notificacion = (
      STR_TO_DATE(NEW.fecha_fallo_notificacion, '%Y-%m-%d') IS NOT NULL AND 
    STR_TO_DATE(NEW.fecha_fallo_notificacion, '%Y-%m-%d') = NEW.fecha_fallo_notificacion
   );

    -- Si la fecha no es válida, ingresamos a la tabla de errores 
   IF NOT fecha_valida_notificacion THEN
        insert into errores_carga(con, mensaje, campo, archivo, created_at)
        values (cast(new.id  as char), 'La fecha no existe', 5, 'SI', now());
   END IF;
   
END
```

Im expecting to handle this error and insert a message in another table just like other errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You should also be aware that, for dates and the date portions of
> datetime values,  `STR_TO_DATE()` checks (only) the individual year,
> month, and day of month values for validity.  More precisely, this
> means that the year is checked to be sure that it is in the range
> 0-9999 inclusive,  the month is checked to ensure that it is in the
> range 1-12 inclusive,  and the day of month is checked to make sure
> that it is in the range 1-31 inclusive,  but the server does not check
> the values in combination. For example,  `SELECT STR_TO_DATE('23-2-31', '%Y-%m-%d')` returns `2023-02-31`.

[`STR_TO_DATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date)

In short: `STR_TO_DATE` considers `2023-02-31` as well as `2023-09-31` to be valid.

But since (at least) your format is already valid, you can use
[`DATE()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date)
instead, which will return `NULL` for `2023-02-31` and `2023-09-31`. Even though they don't tell us much about in the documentation.

Another way:

```
CAST(NEW.fecha_fallo_notificacion as DATE) IS NOT NULL
```

should also work.

Comment: You right, it seems that STR_TO_DATE only checks for range and not for existense. Thanks for your answer